# CSS Lightbox on LOAD

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox

I'm trying to convert this lightbox code to being able to open on load, not on click of the link (which I would want to remove).

I can't seem to get it working.  Any ideas?

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
Show PopUp</a>

 <div class="white_content" id="light">
    <a class="textright" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">
    Close</a>

      <div id="lbcontent">
           <p>THIS IS MY LIGHTBOX CONTENT</p>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="black_overlay" id="fade"></div>
```

Comment: ... don't hide it by default? In your CSS change `#light` to be `display:block;`.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen seems a safe assumption that some kind of CSS transition is involved and he wants to keep that. Otherwise the whole question would be more than pointless.

Comment: Actually it doesn't as he's only modifying `display` properties... maybe this is just sample code hehe.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'
  }, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a js function loadLightBox and call it onload of body tag

```
        <script language="javascript">

        function loadLightBox()
        {    
           document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
           document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
        }

        </script>

        <body onload = "loadLightBox()">

        ...
```